# How to get new update for my listview in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

I want to get the update for my listview whenever i click the back button from the emulator. But i my adapter do not accept notifyDataSetChanged(). Is there a way for me to do this?

**Below is my code for displaying the listview**

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(BookmarkActivity.this,
                        eventsList, R.layout.bookmark_list, new String[] {
                                TAG_EID, TAG_ENAME, TAG_CNAME,
                                TAG_CREATED_AT }, new int[] { R.id.bk_eid,
                                R.id.bk_ename, R.id.bk_cname,
                                R.id.bk_created_at });
                // updating listView
                setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't accept notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: i cannot adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

Call the same code in `onResume()`; I think that will do it:)

Comment: what if my above code is in the async task? i call the async class can?